# Clarification about requireEnd Matcher's method

Tags: java, regex, methods

Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#requireEnd%28%29) java API:

> public boolean requireEnd()
>
> Returns true if more input could change a positive match into a
>   negative one.
>
> If this method returns true, and a match was found, then more input
>   could cause the match to be lost. If this method returns false and a
>   match was found, then more input might change the match but the match
>   won't be lost. If a match was not found, then requireEnd has no
>   meaning.
>
> Returns:
>       true iff more input could change a positive match into a negative one.

I have not been able to find any concrete example on line.

Could somebody show me an example of its use?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us take this simple example:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cat$");

    final Matcher m = p.matcher("I have a cat");
    m.find(); // finds a match
    System.out.println(m.requireEnd()); // prints true
}
```

The regex has an anchor at the end; the documentation says that if more input was given, it "[...]could cause the match to be lost". Indeed. consider this input:

```
"I have a catflap"
```

The regex does not match anymore here: the match is lost.

If now we replace `"cat$"` with `"cat"` then `.requireEnd()` would return `false`: with the input above, `cat` would still be matched by the regex engine.

Comment: So basically it just check if there is a $ at the end of the pattern?

Comment: Not only a `$`; any combination of anchors which causes the match to be bounded at the end. A word anchor, for instance, or a lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

`requireEnd()`, is a matcher method which is used primarily in building scanners.
This method, which is meaningful only after a **successful match**, indicates whether the **regex** engine relied on the location of the end of the input to achieve that success. If `requireEnd` returns `true`, additional input could have caused the attempt to fail. If it returns `false`, additional input could have changed the details of success, but **could not have turned success into failure**.

Its common application is that if `requireEnd` is true, you should accept more input before committing to a decision about the input.

Example:
1. **Regex**: `\d+\b | [><]=?`   **Text:** '1234'    **Match:** '***1234***'
`requireEnd()`: True
2. **Regex**: `\d+\b | [><]=?`   **Text:** '>='     **Match:** '***>=***'
`requireEnd()`: False

So in general, a `return` value of `true` from this method means that, **more input is required before a definite decision can be made**.

For example, if the current input (say, characters being typed by the user in an interactive debugger) is the single character '<', it's best to wait to see whether the next character is '=' so you can properly decide whether the next token should be `LESS_THAN` or `LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL`.

Comment: You could have mentioned where you got these from... http://www.tzlink.com/tool/Mastering_Regular_Expressions_3rd/0596528124/regex3-CHP-8-SECT-4.html