# What do they mean with the following sentence:

Tags: java, regex, stringbuffer

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement) java API:

> Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as
>   described above, **and backslashes are used to escape literal characters**
>    **in the replacement string.**

I get the first bit, However a little confuse about the part underscored in bold.
What do they mean with "to escape literal characters"? what kind of literal characters would you escape in a replacement string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dollar signs. `"\\$"`

Comment: @johnchen902 why did they use the plural then?

Comment: Dunno, I'm not good at grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `$` ;)

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("one dollar");

    final String input = "I want one dollar, please";

    // IndexOutOfBoundsException: no group 1
    System.out.println(p.matcher(input).replaceFirst("$1"));
    // You need to escape the "$"
    System.out.println(p.matcher(input).replaceFirst("\\$1"));
}
```

Comment: Why did they use the plural then? "escape characters"?

Comment: Because you can have more than one `$` in the replacement string? To be honest, I don't see what other characters would need escaping...

Comment: I noticed that you are quite fond of regex, I suggest you this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618812/clarification-about-requireend-matchers-method feel free to answer :)